# Change Active Link Color on Single Menu Item

Tags: css, button, colors, menu

I have created a button on my website menu and want to give it its own individual active link color, how would I go about doing this? In an ideal world, the button would be pink (#ed6d8d) and the active text color would be white. At current the default active menu item color is blue (#00bcd1) so would clash horribly with the pink - any advice would be much appreciated!

I used the following CSS code to create the button:

```
 #in-crisis li a:hover {opacity: 1!important;
    color: #ffffff;}

.in-crisis a {
    border: 2px solid #dbf7ff!important;
    padding: 12px!important;
    margin: 10px 12px 12px 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #dbf7ff;

}

.in-crisis a:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #00bcd1!important;
    border: 2px solid #00bcd1 !important;
}

.et_header_style_left #et-top-navigation {
    padding-top: 16px!important;
}

.et_header_style_left .et-fixed-header #et-top-navigation {
    padding-top: 6px!important;
}

#main-header.et-fixed-header .in-crisis a {
color: #00bcd1 !important;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 980px) {
.in-crisis a {
    background-color: #dbf7ff;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 980px) {
#et_top_search { 
    margin-top: 25px !important; }
}
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you are talking about hover or active but for active css you should use

```
.in-crisis a:active {
  color: white;
  //or anything else here
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working (even though, as far as I can tell, that looks exactly right!) :( I know Divi builder sometimes has issues with changing this particular element, so guess I'll drop them a line...) Thank you for replying, though!